# I cannot send form by using sweetalert 2

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sweetalert2

I read a lot of posts on this but nothing work on my side

I have the follow php code:

```
<?

if( isset($_POST['btn-login']) ) {    
$mails = new PHPMailer;
$content = "xxxx";
$mails->IsSMTP();
$mails->send();
}

?>


<form name="form1" id="form1" class="form1" method="post">
<input class="form-control"  name="oggetto" id="oggetto" required placeholder="Oggetto"  >
<input class="btn-login" type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Invia"/>
</form>
```

with this script:

```
<script>

  $('#btn-submit').on('click',function(e){
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $('.form1');
                console.log("hello");
                swal.fire({
                    title: "Inviare il msg?",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                    confirmButtonText: "Si",
                }).then(function (result){
                    if(result.value === true){
                    console.log(form);
                    $('.form1').submit();
                  }
                });
            });
</script>
```

i can see the popup with sweet alert but when i click on the submit button the form doesn't work.
Pls don't consider parameters of PHPMailer (that are just to understand the structure)

[JFiddle example is here](https://jsfiddle.net/jgpsmd23/1/)

Any help on this?
thanks in advance

Comment: `if( isset($_POST['btn-login'])` There is no element with that name

Comment: yes there is: <input class="btn-login" type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Invia"/>

Comment: No, there isn't: `<input class="btn-login" type="submit" name="submit" id="btn-submit" value="Invia"/>` That's the `class`, not the `name`

Comment: ah... so how to fix? (thanks for your help)

Comment: Use the `name` attribute instead of the `class` attribute in your `if( isset($_POST['btn-login'])`. Might want to read [Dealing with Forms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php) from the PHP manual

Comment: done but the form doesn't send any email... it seems that the javascript doesn't call it...

Comment: Then you need to do some debugging. Any errors in your browsers DevConsole? Could be that `<?` needs to be `<?php`. Create a test php file that _can_ send email, then use those settings (you're missing sender and recipient here) in your script

Comment: no errors in console...  the bad thing is only that it doesn't call the submit action of the form. In jsfiddle i cannot add php code :(

Answer (score 0):

> **The NUMBER ONE error is having ANYTHING with the reserved word `submit` as `id` or `name` in your form.**
>
> If you plan to call `.submit()` on the form AND the form has submit as
> `id` or `name` on any form element, then you need to rename that form
> element, since the form’s submit method/handler is shadowed by the
> name/id attribute.

Also, since the form is submitted via javascript, for some reason, the submit button will not be sent to the server so `if( isset($_POST['btn-login']) )` will not work. You can instead put that `name` value in a hidden input field and use it on the server.

Lastly, for the HTML5 validation(`required`, etc.) to work, you should instead listen to a `submit` event on the form itself rather than the `click` event on the submit button.

This worked for me

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form1').on('submit', function(e){
        let $form = $(this);

        if( this.checkValidity() && $form.data('valid') !== true ){
            e.preventDefault();

            swal.fire({
                title: "Inviare il msg?",
                icon: 'warning',
                showCancelButton: true,
                confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                confirmButtonText: "Si",
            }).then(function (result){
                if(result.value === true){
                    $form.data('valid', true).submit();
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<?php

if( isset($_POST['submit-login']) ){
    print_r($_POST);
}

?>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/limonte-sweetalert2/11.1.9/sweetalert2.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@10/dist/sweetalert2.all.min.js"></script>

<form id="form1" class="form1" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="submit-login">
    <input class="form-control"  name="oggetto" id="oggetto" required placeholder="Oggetto">
    <input type="submit" class="btn-login" id="btn-submit" value="Invia" />
</form>
```

Comment: thanks. I don't know how to mark your answer as closed but I think my comment here is ok. Thanks so much. Perfect answer and solution.